# Move opensolaris zone to other disk

Tags: hard-drive, zfs, opensolaris, zones

We have some opensolaris zones running on ISCSI disks. The ISCSI server has performance issues so we need to move to another storage solution. For now we want to move to local disk. Is there a way to change the disk and keep the zones running?

Thanks
Martijn

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the underlying disk without having an outage. If your zone roots are within a ZFS pool, and you're not using raidz, you can do the following:

1. Use `zpool status` to identify the devices in the pool.
2. Using Solaris tools, identify disk devices that you can use in place of the existing devices. You'll need enough to replace each existing device one-for-one, and each device must be the same size or larger than the one it replaces.
3. Use `zpool attach` to mirror up each existing top-level vdev with its replacement.
4. Monitor the progress of the mirror with `zpool status`.
5. Once the mirrors are complete, use `zpool detach` to remove the old devices.

You can vary this procedure to suit your circumstances. For example, you could attach multiple new devices if you local disks don't have any underlying redundancy.